# What does "de" mean in "Ego de to my liking"?

Tags: grammar-choice

In the classic [school interchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150733/quis-ego-childs-phrase)

> Quis? Ego de to my liking.

What grammatical part is the "de" playing?

Comment: In the linked question, the OP says it "sounds like that" and the answer finds no reference to it. It's also fairly obvious from the context that this could only be a flippant perversion of Latin, so I think I would challenge the premise of the question.

Comment: @brianpck I am 100% sure from personal experience that the expression was in wide use and is at least pronounced as I have written it. It is possible that the "de" is just a meaningless addition but that would be interesting in itself.

Comment: Suggestion: 'dâto my liking' could be an ablative absolute in Macaroni Latin with conditional force.  'Subject to my approval' 'Given that I like it' This long â survives in English pronunciation of 'dative' and Cato, Plato.

Comment: Perhaps some form of wordplay.  Possibly "ego de" is meant to sound like "a goody".